# MigraDoc: Centering a watermark on both landscape and portrait pages

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm looking to add a watermark on all my pages and center it as well.  This is pretty simple to at least 'eyeball' with just a portrait set of pages, but have both portrait and landscape pages in this document.

My researach indicates that it can be done with these elements:

```
myImage.RelativeVertical = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.RelativeVertical.Line;
myImage.RelativeHorizontal = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.RelativeHorizontal.Margin;
```

But I'm not sure how to leverage them to do what I want.  My current code looks like so (repeated for even pages):

```
    var myImage = section.Headers.Primary.AddImage("C:\myImage.png");

    myImage.Height = "4.5cm";
    myImage.LockAspectRatio = true;
    myImage.Top = "2.0cm";
    myImage.Left = "1.5cm";
```

Which is not a centered picture, of course, but I'm hoping to modify this to do what I want it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alas, I was misinterpreting some of the functionality.  Centering across all pages can be done like so:

```
    myImage = section.Headers.EvenPage.AddImage("C:\\myImage.png");

    myImage.Height = "4.5cm";
    myImage.LockAspectRatio = true;
    myImage.Top = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.ShapePosition.Center;
    myImage.Left = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.ShapePosition.Center;
    myImage.RelativeHorizontal = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.RelativeHorizontal.Margin;
    myImage.RelativeVertical = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.RelativeVertical.Margin;
```

Comment: Answer is correct. Tested in my project a few times.